# Elixir Multiple Jason Encoders for same struct

Tags: json, elixir, elixir-jason

Suppose I'm building an API that is versioned (as an example let's use a user object):

```
%User{
  id: "b2507407-891b-486e-aaf8-ba262c16d618"
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Doe",
  email: "john@doe.com"
}
```

My initial thought was to have multiple encoders for different versions of the API I would run different Jason encoders:

```
defimpl Jason.EncoderV1, for: __MODULE__ do
  def encode(user, opts) do
    Jason.Encode.map(%{name: "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"}, opts)
  end
end

defimpl Jason.EncoderV2, for: __MODULE__ do
  def encode(user, opts) do
    Jason.Encode.map(%{first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name}, opts)
  end
end
```

I did not see any reference in the Jason docs that would allow this.

Answer (score 2):

You should somehow tell `Jason` what version do you want to use. [`Jason.Encoder.encode/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.Encoder.html#encode/2) has the second parameter for this.

```rb
defimpl Jason.Encoder, for: __MODULE__ do
  def encode(user, opts) do
    {v, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :version, :v1)

    v
    |> case do
      :v2 -> %{first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name}
      _ -> %{name: "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"}
    end
    |> Jason.Encode.map(opts)
  end
end
```

And call it like `Jason.encode!(any, version: :v2)`.

*Sidenote:* `defimpl` expects the module that defines a protocol as a first parameter, one cannot pass whatever, like inexisting `Jason.EncoderV2` there.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can pass in arbitrary options into an encoder

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code poses a question that is more of a question about Elixir [protocols](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html), but be careful: the [Jason package defines its own protocol](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.Encoder.html) which is not subject to your versioning -- i.e. your implementations of it would always use `defimpl Jason.Encoder`.

However, you could define different implementations for different structs, e.g.

```
defimpl Jason.Encoder, for: UserV1 do
  def encode(user, opts) do
    Jason.Encode.map(%{name: "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"}, opts)
  end
end

defimpl Jason.Encoder, for: UserV2 do
  def encode(user, opts) do
    Jason.Encode.map(%{first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name}, opts)
  end
end
```

Or, leverage the options (2nd argument) as Aleksei has pointed out in his answer.

In other words, you can't change the name of the *protocol* (because it is out of your control), but you can change the functionality by providing different names of different modules (which *you* do control).

Simpler solutions here are less glamorous than protocol implementations:

1. you could simply define JSON views for your different use cases
2. you could write custom `v1` and `v2` functions that would convert the `%User{}` struct to a regular map (with whatever fields are needed for each), and then rely on the standard JSON encoding as provided by your JSON library (`Jason` in your case) and its encoding protocol.

Comment: Simpler options would not work for nested terms `%{foo: :bar, user: %User{}}` which is the main point of the existence of this protocol.